# unable to resolve domain name which are hosted on azure DNS

Tags: azure, dns, cloud, virtual-machine

I have some dns on azure DNS service . All are public DNS. I am able to resolve them from my system. But these domains are not resolving from the VM i created in Azure. VM has public IP and Vnet has servers

```
10.0.0.4
10.0.0.5
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```

I am not sure why these domains are getting resolved from VM. Please let me know if i missed something in configuration.

```
[root@Server ~]# traceroute godqualified.com.dev.spointe.org
godqualified.com.dev.spointe.org: Name or service not known

[root@Server ~]# ping godqualified.com.dev.spointe.org
ping: godqualified.com.dev.spointe.org: Name or service not known
```

If i ping google.com it works fine.

```
[root@Server ~]# ping google.com
PING google.com (142.250.179.142) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ams17s10-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.179.142): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=2.34 ms
64 bytes from ams17s10-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.179.142): icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=2.38 ms
64 bytes from ams17s10-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.179.142): icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=2.64 ms
64 bytes from ams17s10-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.179.142): icmp_seq=4 ttl=53 time=2.51 ms
```

Comment: Hi @user2916639, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•   You are not able to resolve the domain **‘godqualified.com.dev.spointe.org’** from your Azure VM which has a public IP address because, the **DNS request to resolve these is not getting forwarded to the correct DNS server/resolver**. Since, *`you have public DNS servers in Azure, i.e., you might have created your public DNS zone in Azure for name resolution and DNS record management, I would suggest you ensure that your public DNS servers are configured in the DNS zone provisioned and since your VM has a public IP address, ensure that its DNS records are managed and registered by the DNS zone itself`*.

•   Also, as your VM has a public IP address, I would suggest that you should **replace the DNS servers in your virtual network with the ones registered in your Azure DNS zone**. You can do that in the `NIC configuration of the VM also but please be aware that if some configuration is changed and then VM becomes unreachable, then it cannot be reconnected again, thus ensure to take a snapshot of the VM before doing any changes to the NIC configuration`.

Once, the `virtual network’s DNS servers are replaced with the ones as said above, then any domain can be resolved from within the VM as the DNS requests will be forwarded to the public DNS servers in the Azure DNS zone` and since, the *`VM is already registered in the Azure DNS zone, it will also use the Azure DNS for resolving DNS requests over the internet`*. In this way, you can resolve any public domain from your Azure VM.

For more information regarding **configuring conditional forwarding from your DNS servers to Azure provided default DNS**, kindly refer to the below documentation link: -

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances#name-resolution-that-uses-your-own-dns-server**